# FPGA project sanity check, PCIE and video processeing

Tags: fpga, video, intel-fpga, pcie

I have an [Altera DE4](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?No=501) education FPGA that I'd like to use for video processing... But the thing doesn't have many ports to work with, and I don't have the funds to purchase any daughter boards.

My plan is to plug the FPGA into my computer via the PCIE port, and then send video to the board that way.

Will this work?  Or am I just grasping at straws here?  Was it much trouble to interface with the board in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be made to work, certainly.

There appears to be a PCIe image processing reference design listed on [the product page at Terasic](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=138&No=501&PartNo=4), which bodes well for you!

Comment: ...You have no idea how much this answer has brightened my day.  I thought I was hosed.